# How to trigger multiple time onChange for the same item in material ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I use autocomplete component in material ui.

Each time I select an item, it will trigger onChange props and then does some stuff behind..

But the problem is, that, in my case, we could select multiple time the same object but onChange work only when I select a different item

I would like to know if there is a way to select two time the same item and get the event each time

Here a sandbox to illustrate my problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ds9iz

When you select an item, a console.log will print the item selected, the goal is to select two time the same item and get the event two time

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to [mcve] for better support

Comment: I have updated my post with sandbox link :)

Comment: I think you'd better close this and reopen one with the tag `react`, since that's the most important index to expose for others

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario, the troubleshooting was to implement the `renderOption` prop and make our own custom item, attaching a click handler:

```
 renderOption={(props, option) => (
            <ListItem ...
```

so it won't care if the item clicked was previously selected or not